# Sharepoint - Assign Task to users which belong to two groups?

Tags: sharepoint

I am working on a project in which a task needs to be assigned to users that potentially belong to two groups. For example - users which belong to Company A and also are User Type B. Is it possible to have two columns in the task list and require the workflow to assign the task only to users which are members of groups in both columns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be achieved with OOTB approval workflow since you have to get intersection of users from both the groups. The simplest way will be create another group which will contain only  users which belong to Company A and also are User Type B.

You can maintain this group manually or in SP2013 create a SPGroup User added event receiver which will automate this process.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/create-groupuseradded-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/